# "this.domNode is null" when extending Dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to setup a custom dialog using the same templateString as Dialog but with adding `<div><div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane">Custom</div></div>` into the content area.

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dijit/Dialog"
], function (declare, lang, domConstruct, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Dialog) {
    var CustomDialog = declare([Dialog, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: 
            '<div class="dijitDialog" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="${id}_title">'+
                '<div data-dojo-attach-point="titleBar" class="dijitDialogTitleBar">'+
                    '<span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitDialogTitle" id="${id}_title"'+
                              'role="heading" level="1"></span>'+
                    '<span data-dojo-attach-point="closeButtonNode" class="dijitDialogCloseIcon" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: onCancel"'+
                        'title="${buttonCancel}" role="button" tabindex="0">'+
                        '<span data-dojo-attach-point="closeText" class="closeText"'+ 'title="${buttonCancel}">x</span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                '</div>'+
               ' <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="dijitDialogPaneContent">'+
                    '<div><div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane">Custom</div></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>' ,
        constructor: function (args, srcNodeRef) {
            lang.mixin(this, args);
        },
    });  

    var div = domConstruct.toDom("<div id='saveMapWidget'></div>");
    domConstruct.place(div, document.body);    
    var widget = new CustomDialog({}, div);
    widget.startup();
    widget.show();
});
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shoe788/equny0hh/)

Running this code gives me `TypeError: this.domNode is null`

Removing `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` causes it to work correctly. Why are template widgets causing this to break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited my response because while my original reply is a valid point, it's not what was causing the issue, as Shoe pointed out.  Sorry about that.

I've traced through this more closely.  What's happening is your inner `ContentPane` is actually being destroyed before the dialog ever starts up, and then when it *does* attempt to start up, it attempts to start up the already-destroyed `ContentPane`.  However, destroyed widgets have their `domNode` references nullified, and `ContentPane` looks at `domNode.parentNode` indirectly during its `startup` function, which leads to the error.

IIUC, the reason the widget is getting prematurely destroyed in the first place is because your dialog is parsing widgets in the template during `buildRendering`, then immediately after `buildRendering` in `_applyAttributes`, the `content` setter for the `Dialog` ends up called with the content that was originally parsed, and this ends up destroying the originally parsed content.  In effect, you're double-parsing by attempting to use `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` here.  Presumably you wouldn't have this problem if you rendered widgets somewhere outside of `containerNode` (which is the node that `ContentPane` specifically parses).

FWIW, when I need to put a custom widget in a dialog, I don't like to have to fiddle with the entire dialog's template, so I take the reverse approach - I develop the custom widget, then simply set the dialog's `content` to an instance of that custom widget.  That might be a more straightforward approach for you to try.

Here's an example of the widget-as-content approach: http://jsfiddle.net/ddLp24wg/

#### Original response

You are calling `startup` before the dialog is actually within document flow and one of the child widgets is not expecting that.  A widget's `startup` method should only be called once the widget's DOM is in document flow, as `startup` is the one API during the creation lifecycle where dimension-sensitive logic can be performed.

In the case of Dialogs, `startup` will be called automatically the first time `show` is called anyway (since it isn't expected to be in flow before then), so you shouldn't need to call it yourself at all.

Also, I'm not sure if you're only testing so far, but if you're extending the template to add a `ContentPane`, that's overkill - `Dialog` already extends `ContentPane` to begin with, so you've essentially already got one.

Comment: If I comment out `widget.startup()` the error remains. Why would that be? My overall goal is to have a few (non-layout) widgets in the `containerNode`. ContentPane was merely for demonstration.

Comment: Whoops.  Yup.  Looks like I got that all wrong.  I tried again and edited my response.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ken. Originally I had been setting the content instead of building the template. However I found that attachPoints and attachEvents weren't being wired at all. If I bundle the stuff that I want in the containerNode into another widget and then set the content of the dialog to that widget, will the declarative attach points and events be parsed and attached correctly to my widget?

Comment: Yes, the templated widget instance you pass as `content` will have access to its attach points just like any other templated widget.  This differs from setting mixed content directly, which as you observed, won't heed attach points/events at all.  Here's an example of setting a templated widget as content: http://jsfiddle.net/ddLp24wg/  In addition, you should be able to access the dialog via `this.getParent()` within the content widget.

Comment: Great to hear. Thanks for all your help Ken.